# How to customise overlays and height of description block in descriptive diagram?

Tags: beamer, overlays, smartdiagram

I am creating a descriptive diagram in a beamer presentation. I want them to appear step by step (description title and description both should appear on one click). The MWE is

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
    {Set up,The set up operation consist of..},
    {Run, {After having set up the program, you must run..}},
    {Analyse, You must check what did with analytical tools like..},
    {Modify, {After the analysis, you can still modify or add..}},
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

1. How can I achieve the step by step (as mentioned above) overlay effect?
2. How can I adjust the height of description block?

Comment: The answer to the second question is easy: `\smartdiagramset{module minimum height=0.5cm}`.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick workaround to show the title and body text at the same time:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<2,4,6,8>
\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
    {Set up,The set up operation consist of..},
    {Run, {After having set up the program, you must run..}},
    {Analyse, You must check what did with analytical tools like..},
    {Modify, {After the analysis, you can still modify or add..}},
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```